# Is Duotrope worth using?

Tags: publishing

I am a new writer trying to simplify the publishing process. It seems to overwhelming. What are your experiences of Duotrope? Is it worthwhile?

Comment: I can't understand why there are votes to close this. It seems to be about writing and publishing.

Comment: @S.Mitchell Because asking for opinions on a tool is by definition *opinion-based*. Whether something is "worth using" will vary based on use case and personal circumstances. Without additional details how would we determine if it is "worth using" for the OP?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

I have used Duotrope extensively for about 4 or 5 years. Most of my publications (poetry) have come through journals and small press publishers that I found using Duotrope.

While you can do some searching (I think) without paying, one of the things that membership gets you is a look at the statistics for the market. If I see a site that doesn't respond 40% of the time, I'm not going to waste my energy with them.

You also have interviews with editors for some of the publications.

Personally, I put together searches based on my needs, save the searches, favorite journals that I intend to send to, etc. It also allows me to track where my submissions have gone, how long before I should expect a response, etc. For $5 a month (I think less if you pay by the year), I find it worth it.